# Making a map of Mat and strings

Tags: c++, opencv, dictionary

I want to make a Map of Mat and a string for each Mat, but I get an error.

```
map <Mat,string> skinImages;
Mat skinMat=imread("test.png",1);
pair<Mat,string> test=pair<Mat,string>(skinMat,"asd");
skinImages.insert(test);

Error   3   error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'cv::MatExpr' to 'bool' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstddef  180 1
```

Anyone got an idea why? I tried to make a Vector of Mat and it worked, but map will not work.

Comment: since you want to use it as a key, you need a 'less' operator for cv::Mat. the builtin op for a<b returns a MatExpr, but you need a bool. do you need an ordered map at all ?

Comment: I see. I just need to store values in pairs.

Comment: why not a map<string,Mat> ?